# How to change the hierarchical data to join 4 tables if only one table is common?

Tags: mysql

To practice sql, I try to create a *music* database with the following tables:

*Song table:* released songs (as a file)

```
+----+----------+-----------+--------------+----------+----------+
| ID | album_id | artist_id | extension_id | SongName |   Date   |
+----+----------+-----------+--------------+----------+----------+
```

*Album table:* the albums of the songs

```
+----------+------------+
| album_id | album_name |
+----------+------------+
```

*Artist table:* the artists of the songs and albums

```
+-----------+-------------+
| artist_id | artist_name |
+-----------+-------------+
```

*Extension table:* the extensions of the files (mp3,m4a,wav...)

```
+--------------+-----------+
| extension_id | extension |
+--------------+-----------+
```

My SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM Song as s
    INNER JOIN Album as a 
        ON s.album_id = a.album_id 
    INNER JOIN Artist as b 
        ON s.artist_id = b.artist_id
    INNER JOIN Extension as e
        ON s.extension_id = e.extension_id
    ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Unfortunately **the query doubles the result** (maybe cause of "Cartesian product").
How should I change the query/hierarchical data?

Comment: This is NOT hierarchical data. *the query doubles the result* - this means that at least one of referential fields - album_id, artist_id or extension_id,- is not unique (the table has duplicated record, or listed field only).

Comment: Given the information, how do you think we can help???  At least tell us the relationship between each table.  For example, what is `Extension` table contain?

Comment: @Akina I think it is caused by the extension table.

Comment: That's your data (not structure or query) problem.

Comment: @Eric I use that table to determine the file extension. For example, if someone save the project, it could be mp3, m4a, flac, etc.